# MVC multiselect selected values without model

Tags: c#, forms, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have got a simple form and it has got a `MultiSelectList` inside. This form method is GET. When I choose more items in `SelectList` and submit form, I want to see what I choose. I use `SelectedValues` for that. But it selects only first item in `MultiSelectList`.

My View :

```
<form method="get">
    @Html.DropDownList("kategori", new MultiSelectList(ViewBag.KategoriSelect, "id", "isim", ViewBag.KategoriSelected),
 new
 {
     @multiple = "true ",
     @size = "8"
 })

    <input type="submit" value="gönder" />
</form>
```

My Controller :

```
    public ActionResult Index(int[] kategori)
    {
        var db = new MyDbContext();

        var aracs = db.aracs.ToList();

        //items for multi select
        ViewBag.KategoriSelect = db.kategoris.ToList();

        //selected items
        ViewBag.KategoriSelected = kategori;

        return View(aracs);
    }
```

My Get URL : `http://localhost:6151/?kategori=2&kategori=1&kategori=4&kategori=3`

HTML output :
[image: Html Output for multi select]

But it must select all item. what must I do for that ?

Comment: Do it property and use a view model with properties `int[] SelectedCategories` and `IEnumerabe<SelectListItem> CategoryList`

Comment: Can you give an example for that ?

Comment: OP already has a `int[] kategori` in his ActionResult and jsut by making it a Viewmodel property will not help. BTW @ASPMaker did you get this fixed or still need help?

Comment: There's a simalar problem solved here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3763711/390421

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on similar scenario where we use
https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect

Bootstrap Multiselect which can be loaded as list fro C# and converts to Multiselect with built in JS library.