# MVC MultiSelectList not selecting selected values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, multi-select

I have multiselect dropdown which doesn't populate selected values. It populates all values but selected values are not populating. At the time of debugging I can see the values but its not getting rendered.

```
@Html.DropDownList("UnitsSelected", new MultiSelectList(Model[0].UnitsSelected, "Value", "Text",  
    Model[0].UnitsSelected.Where(x => x.Selected).ToList()), 
new { @class = "alignCenter", multiple = "multiple", id = "companyUnits" })
```

I tried solution given in [ASP.NET MVC MultiSelectList with selected values not selecting properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737985/asp-net-mvc-multiselectlist-with-selected-values-not-selecting-properly)
But it doesn't solve my case.

Comment: i think you are missing a `select`.

Comment: @Stephen Muecke I tried that also. But it is not helping.

Comment: @Kumar_Vikas I did not get you.

Comment: What is not working - you must use `ListBoxFor()`, but the fact you have `Model[0].UnitsSelected` suggests this is in a loop, which means your not binding to anything

Comment: @TBAG `Model[0].UnitsSelected.Where(x => x.Selected).select(m=>m.id).ToList()` something like this.i am just assuming your selected value to be `id`.

Comment: ListBox and select id both worked. Thanks